# "Infinitely often" interpretation of lim sup of sequence of sets

Tags: measure-theory

One type of interpretation of the lim sup and lim inf of a sequence of sets is as follows:

$\text{lim sup}_n A_n = \{ \omega: \omega \in A_n \text{ for infinitely many } A_n \}$

$\text{lim inf}_n A_n = \{ \omega: \omega \in A_n \text{ for all but finitely many } A_n \}$

I don't understand the difference between these two statements. Since there are infinitely many $A_n$, I am tempted to conclude that the latter statement automatically implies that $\omega \in A_n$ for infinitely many $A_n$?

Is the difference basically that elements lim sup are not necessarily in the lim inf, because they might occur in **every single** $A_n$, whereas elements of the lim inf are definitely in the lim sup?

Comment: No. or example, let $w$ be in $A_1,A_3,A_5...$ but not be in $A_2,A_4,A_6$ and so on.  Then $w$ belongs to the $\limsup$ but not the $\liminf$. The $\liminf$ is contained in the $\limsup$, but the converse is not true.

Comment: Basically the difference is whether there are infinitely many $A_n$ that $\omega$ is *not* in.

Comment: Along with the things others have said, perhaps this will help with seeing the main idea. For the limsup, you want all those elements that are in "a lot" of the indexed sets. For the liminf, you take fewer elements by imposing a stronger condition --- the elements not only have to be in "a lot" of the indexed sets, but they have to be in so many of the indexed sets that there are "very few" of the indexed sets they are not in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Infinitely many" is a consequence of "all but finitely many", but it's not the same. For example, there are infinitely many even numbers; it is not the case that all but finitely many whole numbers are even, because $1, 3, 5, \ldots$ are not even. On the other hand, all but finitely many whole numbers are greater than twelve; $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 12$ are not, but the list of counterexamples stops there.

Another way of thinking about "all but finitely many" is "eventually". In other words, $\omega \in A_n$ for *all* $n$ past a certain point. "Infinitely many" just means it always reappears when it leaves; "all but finitely many" means it eventually stops leaving at all.

Comment: Yes, *eventually* is a very good word to describe "all but finitely many". And the used word for "infinitely many", if Im not wrong, is *frequently*.

Answer (score 2):

> Since there are infinitely many $A_n$, I am tempted to conclude that the latter statement automatically imply that $ω∈A_n$ for infinitely many $A_n$?

You are correct. To rephrase what you said, $w \in$ lim inf$_n A_n \implies w \in$ lim sup$_n A_n$. This is true since lim inf$_n A_n \subset$ lim sup$_n A_n$. Think of partial ordering via set inclusion: as we may intuitively ascertain, lim inf$_n A_n$ is "less than" lim sup$_n A_n$, by inclusion.

A good way to start wrapping your head around these terminologies is by defining them more concretely as follows:

lim sup$_n A_n := \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k$

lim inf$_n A_n := \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \bigcap_{k \geq n} A_k$

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think of set theoretic limits is using indicator functions:

$$
x \in \textstyle\limsup_nA_n \iff \limsup_n \mathbf{1}_{A_n}(x) = 1,
$$
which holds if and only if the binary sequence $\{\mathbf{1}_{A_n}(x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has infinitely many ones, i.e., $x$ is a member of infinitely many $A_n$.

Similarly, we have
$$
x \in \textstyle\liminf_nA_n \iff \liminf_n \mathbf{1}_{A_n}(x) = 1,
$$
here, we note that since $\{\mathbf{1}_{A_n}(x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is composed of $1$s and $0$s, the above statement is equivalent to $\lim_n \mathbf{1}_{A_n}(x) = 1$, which holds if and only if sequence eventually becomes $1$ forever.